# Escaping 2017-03-30 gives 7-03-30 Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, disqus

I am trying to output the current page URL for Disqus comments. Since my page URL structure is like:

```
https://www.example.com/post/1234/2017-03-30/
```

I am having a little issue with escaping 2017-03-30.

I don't know if this has been asked before, I tried searching for reasonable answer but couldn't find any. I am trying to escape date, since including it like 2017-03-30 will only subtract it.

This is the PHP code that outputs Javascript:

```php
echo 'this.page.url = "https://www.example.com/post/'. $id . '/\\'. $date . '\\/";';
```

Although the output would be:

```
this.page.url = "https://www.example.com/post/1234/\2017-03-30\/";
```

But the problem is Disqus will show the URL like:

```
https://www.example.com/post/1234/7-03-30
```

I know the problem is with \201 but what I don't know is how to fix it. I tried different ways. Nothing seems to be working. I am pretty much lost here. :/

Comment: I'm confused by the initial problem… what exactly is wrong with `2017-03-30`…? Where/what/how/when is subtracting it…?

Comment: I assume by "backslahing", you actually mean "escaping"?

Comment: Andrew, do you mean like this? `echo 'this.page.url = "https://www.example.com/post/'. $id . '/\'. $date . '\/";';`

Comment: Also, why do you have `'/\\'`?  What's with all those slashes?  What are you trying to do?  Why not just `'/'`?  Why do you need the other slashes?

Comment: Removing only '\' would give: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '\'`

Comment: @RocketHazmat, this is what Disqus comments will show the URL if it's only '/' and not '/\\': https://www.example.com/post/3509. And yes, I mean escaping. Sorry!

Comment: I'm not sure I believe that `echo 'this.page.url = "https://www.example.com/post/'. $id . '/'. $date . '/";';` fails to work.  Where is `this.page.url` appearing in your JavaScript?  What do you see if you do `console.log(this.page.url);` right after?  Where is Disqus showing you this "incorrect" URL?

Comment: How can I avoid escaping \201 in "www.example.com/post/3576/\2017-03-30\/", that's my question.

Comment: Does `echo 'this.page.url = "https://www.example.com/post/'. $id . '/'. $date . '/";';` *really* not work for you?  I have no idea why you're trying to add backslahes to a URL.  That's not the solution here.  If this does not work, then the error is elsewhere in your (probably JavaScript) code.

Comment: So, you've tried posting a comment from your page with that code in place, and it didn't appear with the correct URL in Disqus?

Comment: Yup, that's the problem.

Comment: Then the problem must be *elsewhere*.  Probably in the JavaScript code you're using to post comments or something.  I still fail to believe that part of the URL is missing when setting `this.page.url` properly (without any backslahes).

Comment: Yeah, I guess. Tried replacing the URL with `document.URL;` and same problem; date missing. Guess I'll have to avoid using date entirely. Thank you, though! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a JavaScript string, `\201` is an octal escape, giving you the character `U+0081`, which is an unused control character and therefore not displayed.

If the backslash is actually needed, you will need to double-escape it so that the resulting JavaScript looks like `\\2017-03-30\\`, so the PHP would need to be `\\\\'.$date.'\\\\`

When you get this many backslashes, though, it's a sure sign you're doing something wrong.

Comment: +0.5 for correct answer and +0.5 for the last statement.